# Vim, foldexpr, like folding in outshine.el effect on init.el

Tags: vim

I would like to get `foldexpr` to work on my `.emacs` file like `outshine.el` does. In other words, I would like to get the fold levels as in this example:

```
        0
;;;     0
        1
        1
;;;;    1
        2
        2
;;;;;   2
        3
;;;;    1
        2
;;;     0
        1
        1
```

(Notation like that found at [Advanced Folding _ Learn Vimscript the Hard Way](http://learnvimscriptthehardway.stevelosh.com/chapters/49.html).)

In summary, I think the `foldexpr` will have to check current lines and previous lines.

If the current line has at least 3 `;`, then fold level will be 3 less. Otherwise, if the previous line has at least 3, the current will have fold level 2 less, else fold level should be equal to previous line.

That is the effect I tried to achieve with

```
function ELispLevel() 
    let n = len(matchstr(getline(v:lnum), '^;\+'))
    let m = len(matchstr(getline(v:lnum-1), '^;\+'))
    if n >= 2
        return ">" . n-3
    else 
        if m >= 2
            return ">" . m-2
        else 
            return "=" 
    endif 
endfunction
```

(Credit for most of the code goes to the discussion of markdown folding at [Vim Markdown Folding? - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3828606/vim-markdown-folding), especially a comment by Omar Antolín-Camarena.)

I am guessing this does not work. Some of my less trivial modifications include the `n-3` and `m-2`, so maybe I just screwed up the syntax there. But I'm afraid my error could be anywhere, and hope someone can find it.

I also have the following to try to activate it for my `init.el` file,

```
aug filetype_lisp
    au!
    " au FileType lisp setl fdm=marker fmr=;;;,;;+
    au FileType lisp setlocal foldmethod=expr foldexpr=ELispLevel()
aug END
```

(BTW, a third link that I learned some of this from is [vim - Explaining foldexpr syntax - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5977895/explaining-foldexpr-syntax))

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First I had to delete a useless `v:lnum` in an `autocmd` line, and use `let`s for the subtractions. Once folding worked at all, I've reassessed and found my desired level assignment was incorrect. I think it should be

```
        0
;;;     1
        1
        1
;;;;    2
        2
        2
;;;;;   3
        3
;;;;    2
        2
;;;     1
        1
        1
```

I did not anticipate how Vim actually does it's folding. This seems actually easier to implement.

It works!

```
function! ELispLevel() 
    let n = len(matchstr(getline(v:lnum), '^;\+'))
    let m = n - 2
    if n >= 3
        return ">" . m
    else 
        return "=" 
    endif 
endfunction
```